# How to scrape multiple url's in selenium driver without getting a error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape multiple urls using selenium webdriver. They are all working separately, but when i'm trying to run all of them at once, it gets me an error.

This is the code:

```
url_fortuna = "https://efortuna.ro/"
url_betfair = 'https://www.betfair.ro/sport/'
url_mozzart = 'https://www.mozzartbet.ro/ro#/betting'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url_mozzart)

matches_mz = driver.find_elements( By.CLASS_NAME, value='pairs' )
odds_mz = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[class='odd-font betting-regular-match font-18']")))

for event_mz in matches_mz:
    dictionar = {'casa': '',
                 'nume': '',
                 '1': '',
                 'x': '',
                 '2': ''}
    dictionar['casa'] = 'mozzart'
    match_mz = event_mz.text
    dictionar['nume'] = match_mz
    dictionar['1'] = odds_mz[x].text
    dictionar['x'] = odds_mz[x+1].text
    dictionar['2'] = odds_mz[x+2].text
    x= x+3
    evenimente.append(dictionar)

driver.get(url_unibet)

matches_ub = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-test-name='scoreboard']")))
odds_ub = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-test-name='outcomeBet']")))

for event_ub in matches_ub:
    dictionar = {'casa': '',
                 'nume': '',
                 '1': '',
                 'x': '',
                 '2': ''}
    dictionar['casa'] = 'unibet'
    match_ub = event_ub.text
    dictionar['nume'] = match_ub
    dictionar['1'] = odds_ub[x].text
    dictionar['x'] = odds_ub[x+1].text
    dictionar['2'] = odds_ub[x+2].text
    x= x+3
    evenimente.append(dictionar)

driver.get(url_getsbet)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='cookie_consent_btn']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='SportsBookIframe']")))
events_gb = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='Details__Participants']")))
odds_gb = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OM-ValueChanger']")))

for event_gb in events_gb:
    dictionar = {'casa': '',
                 'nume': '',
                 '1': '',
                 'x': '',
                 '2': ''}
    dictionar['casa'] = 'getsbet'
    match_gb = event_gb.text
    dictionar['nume'] = match_gb
    dictionar['1'] = odds_gb[x].text
    dictionar['x'] = odds_gb[x+1].text
    dictionar['2'] = odds_gb[x+2].text
    x= x+3
    evenimente.append(dictionar)

driver.quit()
```

And this is the error that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flr_1\PycharmProjects\scrapper\main.py", line 81, in <module>
    dictionar['1'] = odds_gb[x].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When i comment two of the urls, the third works, no matter which one it is, so i guess the error is caused by scrapping multiple urls. How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

What parts of the code are you commenting to make it work? By looking at it the, it seems that you are not re defining "x" causing it to continue to add up by 3 until the last url where the value is too high causing it to try to get an index value that doesn't exist, i would try re defining x to see if that works, also as a note you can use functions to avoid repeating sections of code and you can use a for loop to iterate through a list if you are uncertain how long is it.

Comment: now i initialized x=0 in every loop and it works, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you are checking an element that does not exist in a list.

The line:

```
odds_gb = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OM-ValueChanger']")))
```

Returns a list of the found elements. If the list only contains one element and you try to access an element higher than what you have (first one is `0` and second one is `1`...), that exception will be triggered.

So you have to check the DOM of the page and verify how are the elements changing in that scenario or what does the `x` have in your code.